# R "TIDYMODELS" Error: Not all functions are allowed in step function selectors (e.g. `all_nominal_predictors`)

Tags: r, recipe, tidymodels

I read "Tidy modeling with R" online book and stuck with an error in demos

```
library(tidymodels)
library(modeldata)

# 1. Data
data(ames)

# 2. 80/20 samples
set.seed(123)
ames_split <- initial_split(ames, prop = 0.8)
ames_train <- training(ames_split)
ames_test <- testing(ames_split)

# 3. Define recipe
simple_ames <- 
  ames_train %>% 
  recipe(Sale_Price ~ Neighborhood + Gr_Liv_Area + Year_Built + Bldg_Type) %>%
  step_log(Gr_Liv_Area, base = 10) %>% 
  step_dummy(all_nominal_predictors())

# 4. Preparing the recipe
simple_ames <- prep(simple_ames, training = ames_train)
```

The last line gives me the error "Error: Not all functions are allowed in step function selectors (e.g. `all_nominal_predictors`). See ?selections."

Any help on how to fix it welcome!

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error. Runs fine for me. What R version and tidymodels version do oyu have?

Comment: It is R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20)

Comment: https://github.com/tidymodels/recipes/issues/329 suggests, that this is a bug which has been resolved (06/19). I would go updating the  tidymodels package.